# Firebase Realtime Rules: Split users into multiple groups w/ role-based (token) authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Each user is authenticated w/ a token of state and city.

I want the users to be able to read data at **/data/$state**, **/data/$state/$city**

For /data/$state/$city I can add a rule (on /data/$state/$city):
`.read: $state == auth.token.state && $city == auth.token.city",`

This would work well, how ever to grant access to /data/$state access I would write (on /data/$state):
`.read: $state == auth.token.state",`

Which would grant read access down the line to any node in any city (in the state, /data/$state/*) and ignore the previous one (based on Firebase Realtime rules where top rules takes precedence).

Do I have any way to handle this beside flattening my data into:

**/Cities/$state/$city**

**/States/$state**

Thus handling security for each case in their respective node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax?authuser=0#read_and_write_rules_cascade), it is not possible:

> `.read` and `.write` rules work from top-down, with shallower rules
> overriding deeper rules.
>
> ...
>
> Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. Child rules
> can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already
> declared. **They cannot revoke a read or write privilege**.

---

So you indeed need to denormalize your data as mentioned at the end of your question. Note that the `update()` method allows to easily write to different nodes, see the example in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#update_specific_fields).